# I guess I didn't understand the Work manager structure

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I can understand that this library is doing operations in the background, but what kind of operation is meant by these operations, backing up data or data that can update UI data ?

Because whenever I send information to update UI data, I encounter errors similar to the following.

Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

unfortunately I think I couldn't understand the work manager structure somehow

Comment: You do not update the UI directly from a `Worker`, if that is what you mean. Instead, your UI [observes the work results](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#observing) or [observes progress in that work](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress).

Comment: @CommonsWare so then how do they update the UI on the image captures inside the database?

Comment: I do not know what "image captures inside the database" you are referring to.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just mentioned it as an example.